# GeoPandas spatial join with conditions / additional columns

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I have two DataFrames with `Lat`, `Long` columns and other additional columns. For example,

```
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
  
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                        'id': [0, 1, 2],
                        'dt': [01-01-2022, 02-01-2022, 03-01-2022],
                        'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480],
                        'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]
                      })
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                        'val': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                        'dt': [01-01-2022, 02-01-2022, 03-01-2022],
                        'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480],
                        'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]
                      })
```

I'd like to do a spatial join not just on `lat`, `long` but also on date column. Expected output:

| id | dt | lat | long | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-01-2022 | 33.155480 | -96.731630 | a |
| 1 | 02-01-2022 | 33.155480 | -96.731630 | b |
| 2 | 03-01-2022 | 33.155480 | -96.731630 | c |

Comment: This post does not meet our quality standards. you need to add "Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem". [check this guideline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). No reason that [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html) ```sjoin``` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can spatial join, then select rows where dates match:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2], 'dt': ["01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022"], 'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480], 'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]})
df1["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["dt"]) #String to datetime
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df1["Long"], y=df1["Lat"]), crs="epsg:4326") #Create a geodataframe

#    id         dt       Lat      Long                    geometry
# 0   0 2022-01-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)
# 1   1 2022-02-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)
# 2   2 2022-03-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'val': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'dt': ["01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022"], 'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480], 'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]})
df2["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["dt"])
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df2["Long"], y=df2["Lat"]), crs="epsg:4326")

#   val         dt       Lat      Long                    geometry
# 0   a 2022-01-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)
# 1   b 2022-02-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)
# 2   c 2022-03-01  33.15548 -96.73163  POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)

df3 = gpd.sjoin(df1, df2) #Spatial join
df3 = df3.loc[df3["dt_left"]==df3["dt_right"]] #Select the rows with matching dates

#id dt_left Lat_left    Long_left   geometry    index_right val dt_right    Lat_right   Long_right
#0  2022-01-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163   POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)  0   a   2022-01-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163
#1  2022-02-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163   POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)  1   b   2022-02-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163
#2  2022-03-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163   POINT (-96.73163 33.15548)  2   c   2022-03-01 00:00:00 33.15548    -96.73163
```